# Route::get returns blank in Laravel 8 API

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have installed the newest version of laravel which is Laravel 8. Now, I'm making an API and encountered this weird problem. I'm doing the API wayback Laravel 5.6 so it's not new to me.

**Problem:**

```
Route::apiResource('/test', UserController::class);
```

The GET method returns blank when using postman even when I wrapped it in auth:api middleware to check if {"message":"Unauthenticated."} will be shown but it does not. Meaning, even error is not working. But when I changed my route to post, it worked.

**Here's my route list:**

[image: Route List]

**Here's the POSTMAN response for GET method:**

[image: GET Method]

**Here's the POSTMAN response for POST method:**

[image: POST METHOD]

Here's the controller:

```
public function index()
{
    return response()->json([
        'success'   => true,
        'data'      => ['test' => 'test'],
        'message'   => 'Success'
    ], 200);
}
public function store(Request $request)
{
    return response()->json([
        'success'   => true,
        'data'      => ['test' => 'test'],
        'message'   => 'Success'
    ], 200);
}
```

As you can see they are the same so the postman should returns the same for GET and POST. I already tried route:clear but it doesn't work.

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice. I'll update it using the apiResource that I used.

Comment: Beyond that, I haven't seen the `$this->sendResponse()` approach before, as I typically just use `return response()->json()`, but the fact it works for the `POST` and not the `GET` is a little bizarre... I'll see if I can recreate

Comment: I'm extending a BaseController that has the sendResponse function. I'll update it to match the return.

Comment: That's similar to what I do; my parent Controller typically has  `sendSuccess()` and `sendFail()` methods that basically wrap a call to `response()->json()` with slightly different signatures. I assume you're is similar. And you get the same outcome with `return response()->json(...)`, right?

Comment: Yes, it's a wrapper. I already updated the question.

Comment: that's the api/user. It has two middleware, api and auth:api.

Comment: A long shot, but could it be that the `get` endpoint needs the `Request $request` argument as well since it's a wrapper?

Comment: Same even with Request $request.

Comment: Are you using docker or likewise? Then it's worth trying to restart the container

Comment: I'm not using docker.

Comment: This may be just a displaying issue in postman. Can you check if there is a response body when you select pretty or raw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GET request on `api/test` is captured by the GET route `{vue}`

Comment: You're right. When I comment out the {vue} it worked. Do you have any solution? Thanks.

Comment: @SeeMore declare your routes in order so the {vue} one is the last, check also routeServiceProvider for the order between api/web routes

Comment: Thanks. I'll check routeServiceProvider to change the order of api and web.